# How do I order two components in a JFrame in order for transparency and ActionListeners to work?

Tags: java, transparency, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

When adding two components to a JFrame, where one sits inside another, If I add them in the order, Fullscreen Object, then JPanel, the JPanel displays correctly, but is essentially invisible, i.e it's action listener won't work and the clicks register on the fullscreen object. If I add them the other way round The JPanel works as it should, but doesn't display correctly (It has transparent areas).

This is the code for the Frame I am adding the components to.

```
            gameOBJ = new gameClass(width, height);
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(0);
            frame.add(gameOBJ.UIPanel);
            frame.add(gameOBJ);
            frame.validate();
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setBounds(0, 0, width, height);
            frame.setResizable(false);

            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
                        {
                            new exitWindow("Don't forget to save your game! \n Are you sure you want to Exit?", true);
                        }
                });
            frame.setVisible(true);
            gameOBJ.start();
```

Here is the code for the JPanel (Stripped down for simplicity's sake)

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class UserInterface extends JPanel implements ActionListener
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Image image;

    private int xBound = 800;
    private int yBound = 177;

    private JButton mainMenuButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("res/images/MainMenuButton.gif"));

    private int buttonWidth = 179;
    private int buttonHeight = 52;

    public UserInterface()
        {
            this.setLayout(null);
            this.image = new ImageIcon("res/images/UIPanelImage.gif").getImage();
            this.setOpaque(false);
            this.setSize(this.xBound, this.yBound);
            mainThreeButtons(); //ONLY ONE SHOWN FOR SIMPLICITY
        }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this); //IMAGE CONTAINS TRANSPARENCY
        }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            else if (event.getSource() == mainMenuButton)
                {
                    new mainMenuWindow();
                }
        }

    private void mainThreeButtons()
        {
            this.add(mainMenuButton);
            mainMenuButton.addActionListener(this);
            //mainMenuButton.setOpaque(false);
            mainMenuButton.setBorderPainted(false);
            mainMenuButton.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            mainMenuButton.setBounds(617, 6, buttonWidth, buttonHeight);
        }
}
```

I would show an image but I'm not allowed to, The area which is meant to be transparent isn't showing the frame, because it is grey, whatever I set as the Frame's background, OR the panel's background, as again it is grey whatever I set the panel's background colour as.

Comment: Why not *hot-link* to a couple of images at my [media page](http://pscode.org/media/#image)?

Comment: You can remove the JPanel as an ImageObserver in drawImage, although I'm not sure that'll make any difference - i.e. you can update that to be just `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);` unless you intend on doing something with [ImageObserver.imageUpdate()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html#imageUpdate%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).

Comment: without 'super.paintComponent(g);' The problem is exactly the same, I can't remember why I added it now, it doesn't appear to have any effect on any of the code if I remove it!

Comment: What I am trying to do is add two components to my Frame, a plain JPanel with a button, and my gameObject, which renders the game. So even if the GameObject was displaying the same photo every frame the problem would be the same. If I add the object before the Panel, Everything LOOKS fine, the transparency of the Panel works, however all the ActionEvents are intercepted by the object before they reach the Panel so the button doesn't work. If I add the Panel before the object, The ActionEvents are recieved by the JPanel within the panel, and by the object outside the JPanel as would be expected

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use JLabel instead of JPanel.  I know it sounds a bit unintuitive, but I'm not sure JPanel is suited to the purpose you are using it for.  Also, JLabel can have a native ImageIcon set, so try using that.

```
public UserInterface() { // extends JLabel
    this.setImageIcon(new ImageIcon("res/images/UIPanelImage.gif"));
    // or super(~imageicon~)
}
```

Unlikely, but it could be that the image is not yet loaded when it gets drawn.  You should use MediaTracker to manage that more carefully (although I'm not sure ImageIcon if takes care of this for you).

```
final static protected MediaTracker mediatracker = new MediaTracker(new Canvas());
static protected void checkImageIsReady(Image i) {
    mediatracker.addImage(i, 1);
    try {
        mediatracker.waitForAll();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    mediatracker.removeImage(i);
}
```

Comment: If I use the JLabel, can I still add JButtons and implement ActionListener? After all it's not just the image I want, plus the image shows whichever order I add the components to the window, Just the transparency doesn't work, and a grey background is shown instead, also both the GameOBJ and the UserInterface JPanel are updated every frame, because I draw the gameOBJ then draw the UserInterface so the UserInterface is always underneath.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a fuller example so I can run it?

Comment: The problem was that I really didn't understand swing or how its components were meant to be used, I'd accept your answer but it doesn't really fix the program, tbh I think the question needs deleting...